# Hadoop - HDFS - Command to see how a file's splits

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Is there a command line in Hadoop FsShell (or hdfs command) to see what are the splits of a file or to see how a file has been splitted on the data nodes when put in HDFS  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hdfs fsck seems to be what you're after:

```
$ hdfs fsck /import/collections/part-00000 -files -blocks
Connecting to namenode via http://vm28-hulk-priv:50070
FSCK started by usrhadoop (auth:SIMPLE) from /10.237.241.28 for path /import/collections/part-00000 at Thu Mar 19 07:35:15 EDT 2015
/import/collections/part-00000 3620228 bytes, 1 block(s):  OK
0. BP-1201623000-10.237.241.28-1421858661680:blk_1074635302_894483 len=3620228 repl=3

Status: HEALTHY
 Total size:    3620228 B
 Total dirs:    0
 Total files:   1
 Total symlinks:                0
 Total blocks (validated):      1 (avg. block size 3620228 B)
 Minimally replicated blocks:   1 (100.0 %)
 Over-replicated blocks:        0 (0.0 %)
 Under-replicated blocks:       0 (0.0 %)
 Mis-replicated blocks:         0 (0.0 %)
 Default replication factor:    3
 Average block replication:     3.0
 Corrupt blocks:                0
 Missing replicas:              0 (0.0 %)
 Number of data-nodes:          4
 Number of racks:               1
FSCK ended at Thu Mar 19 07:35:15 EDT 2015 in 1 milliseconds


The filesystem under path '/import/collections/part-00000' is HEALTHY
```

Comment: Thanks Svend. Exactly what I needed. I see that we can add -locations as well to see where each split is physically stored on the data nodes. Perfect. Thank you very much.